# Script/Tool predicate for ARM ELF compiled for Thumb OR Arm

Tags: arm, binutils

I have **rootfs** and **klibc** file systems.  I am creating `make` rules and some developers have an older compiler without inter-networking.<sup>note1</sup>  I am trying to verify that all the files get built with **arm** only when a certain version of the compiler is detected.  I have re-built the tree's several times.  I was using `readelf -A` and looking for `Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1`, but this seem to be in **arm** only code (but was built with the interworking compiler) as well as `thumb` code.  I can manually run `objdump -S` and examine the assembler to determine what instruction set is in use.

However, it would be much easier if I had a script/tool predicate so that `find`, etc can be used to search through the *shadow* file systems to look for binaries that may have been missed.  I thought that some of this information would be in the `ELF` header and accessible via `objdump` or `readelf`, but I haven't found anything reliable.

Specifically I am looking for,

1. Compiled 'C' that wouldn't run without a `CONFIG_ARM_THUMB` Linux system.
2. `make` rules that use 'C' compiler flags that choke a non-thumb compilers.

**note1:** Interworking allow easy switching between `thumb` and `arm` modes, and the compiler will automatically generate code to support calling from either mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `readelf -A` output doesn't describe the **elf** contents.  It just describes the capabilities of the *processor* and or *system* that is expected or fed to the compiler.  As I have an `ARM926` CPU which is an `ARMV5TEJ` processor, gcc/ld will always set `Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1` as it just means that `ARMV5TEJ` is recognized as being `Thumb-1` capable.  It says nothing about the code itself.

Examining the Linux [arch/arm/kernel/elf.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/elf.c) routine `elf_check_arch()` shows a check for `x->e_entry & 1`.  This leads to the following script,

```
readelf -h $1 | grep -q Entry.*[13579bdf]$
```

Ie, just look at the initial **ELF** entry value and see if the low bit is set.  This is a fast check that fits the spirit of what I am looking for.  [unixsmurf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563188/unixsmurf) has a good point that the code inside any **ELF** can mix and match **ARM** and **Thumb**.  This maybe ok, if the program dynamically *ids* the CPU and selects an appropriate routine.  Ie, just the presence of a **Thumb** instruction doesn't mean that code will execute.

Just looking at the `entry` value does determine which `gcc` compiler flags were used, at least for `gcc` versions 4.6 to 4.7.

Comment: This answer tells you if `gcc -mthumb` or the like was used.  We can always mix instructions sets (that is what inter-networking is about), but the *entry* will be the primary mode used by the compiler.  A compiler could theoretically generate both types of instructions, but generally they don't.

Answer (score 4):

Since thumb and arm sequences can be freely interchanged within an object file, even within the same section, plain ELF header inspection is not going to help you whether a file includes Thumb instructions or not.

A slightly roundabout and still not 100% foolproof way would be to use `readelf -r` and check if the output contains "R_ARM_THM", indicating a relocation for thumb.

Comment: This is useful, I thought about the "ARM or Thumb" issue. I guess I want to know if it was compiled for **Thumb**; I wasn't anticipating hand-coded assembler. `for i in *; do readelf -r $i | grep -q 'no relocations' || echo $i; done` returns nothing with **klibc**. I guess they don't have any relocation, which will make loading faster.