# Disassembly: Determine whether an instruction set in an ARM ELF binary is Thumb or ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering

I went through the ARM definitions for the ELF format [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf), and didn't find a conclusive answer:

Given an ELF binary (using static analysis only), is there a conclusive way to determine whether a given instruction is using Thumb or ARM, such as a flag in the symbol table entry? Or am I forced to keep track of BL and BLX instructions to check when the processor changes state?

Context: I'm testing IDA on an ARM .so file, and most of the disassembled instructions don't make sense (illogical branch instructions which jump into the middle of other functions, for instance).

Thanks in advance for any help on this one.

Comment: It is as you feared, you need to be like the cpu itself and keep the state (if the binary is stripped there is no chance of knowing modes). However I was under strong belief that IDA was good on that.

Comment: Ouch. IDA does get it right most of the time, but not in some crucial places. I guess I'll need to actually learn to read the opcodes, then force IDA to switch modes when its current output doesn't make any sense. By the way, in case that the binary is not stripped, where do I look to check for processor states? You're welcome to submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script/Tool predicate for ARM ELF compiled for Thumb OR Arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913964/script-tool-predicate-for-arm-elf-compiled-for-thumb-or-arm)

Comment: Let's just duplicate it to a previous question. I don't think I can contribute more than that thread.

Comment: The command `readelf -h $1 | grep -q Entry.*[13579bdf]$` seemed to work well for me.  I could not find any sort of documentation that this works conclusively.  However, my goal was to test a `make` system and compiler flags.  It seems that `thumb` functions always have `|1` to the address; normally this only bites people with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: You can actually mix ARM and Thumb code in one executable.

Comment: I've found an answer to this question [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6085).