# Can _start be the thumb function?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, thumb

Help me please with gnu assembler for arm926ejs cpu.

I try to build a simple program(test.S):

```
.global _start 
_start:
    mov r0, #2
    bx lr
```

and success build it:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as -mthumb -o test.o test.S
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld -o test test.o
```

but when I run the program in the arm target linux environment, I get an error:

```
./test 
Segmentation fault
```

What am I doing wrong?
Can _start function be the thumb func?
or
It is always arm func?

Comment: Have you tried getting a stack trace with gdb?

Comment: (gdb) target remote 192.168.3.16:1234
Remote debugging using 192.168.3.16:1234
0x00008054 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00008054 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) set arm fallback-mode thumb
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x8054: movs r0, #5
(gdb) si
0x00008056 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x8056: bx lr
(gdb) si
0x00008056 in ?? ()
Could not insert single-step breakpoint at 0x0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00008056 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you end with

```
bx lr
```

and you expect Linux to take over after that. That exact line must be the cause of `Segmentation fault`.

You can try to create a minimal executable then try to bisect it to see the guts and understand how an executable is expected to behave.

See below for a working example:

```
.global _start
.thumb_func
_start:
    mov r0, #42
    mov r7, #1
    svc #0
```

compile with

> arm-linux-gnueabihf-as start.s -o start.o && arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
>   start.o -o start_test

and dump to see the guts

> $ arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf -a -W start_test

Now you should notice the odd address of `_start`

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8055
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          160 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         6
  Section header string table index: 3

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00008054 000054 000006 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 00005a 000014 00      0   0  1
  [ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00006e 000031 00      0   0  1
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 000190 0000e0 10      5   6  4
  [ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000270 000058 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00008000 0x00008000 0x0005a 0x0005a R E 0x8000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 

There is no dynamic section in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

There are no unwind sections in this file.

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 14 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00008054     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS start.o
     4: 00008054     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $t
     5: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS 
     6: 0001005a     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _bss_end__
     7: 0001005a     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_start__
     8: 0001005a     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_end__
     9: 00008055     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _start
    10: 0001005a     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_start
    11: 0001005c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __end__
    12: 0001005a     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _edata
    13: 0001005c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _end

No version information found in this file.
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_arch: v4T
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
```

Comment: I know. How fixed it the asm operand. How will be it correct?

Comment: link register ( lr ) is NULL. Do i can initialize lr after _start or it to must done linux dynamic loader?

Comment: For ARM code this can easily be done by the code
sequence:

 mov lr, pc
 bx rX

(where rX is the name of the register containing the function
pointer).  This code does not work for the Thumb instruction set,
since the MOV instruction will not set the bottom bit of the LR
register, so that when the called function returns, it will return in
ARM mode not Thumb mode.

Comment: Instead the compiler generates this
sequence:

 bl _call_via_rX

(again where rX is the name if the register containing the function
pointer).  The special call_via_rX functions look like this:

 .thumb_func
_call_via_r0:
 bx r0
 nop

The BL instruction ensures that the correct return address is stored
in the LR register and then the BX instruction jumps to the address
stored in the function pointer, switch modes if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Can _start be a thumb function (in a Linux user program)?

Yes it can.  The steps are not as simple as you may believe.

Please use the `.code 16` as described by others.  Also look at [ARM Script predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913964/script-tool-predicate-for-arm-elf-compiled-for-thumb-or-arm); my answer shows how to detect a *thumb* binary.  The entry symbol must have the traditional `_start+1` value or Linux will decide to call your `_start` in **ARM** mode.

Also your code is trying to emulate,

```
 int main(void) { return 2; }
```

The `_start` symbol must not do this (as per [auselen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163019/auselen)).  To do `_start` to `main()` in **ARM** mode you need,

```
 #include <linux/unistd.h>
 static inline void exit(int status)
 {
         asm volatile ("mov      r0, %0\n\t"
                 "mov    r7, %1\n\t"
                 "swi    #7\n\t"
                 : : "r" (status),
                   "Ir" (__NR_exit)
                 : "r0", "r7");
 }
 /* Wrapper for main return code. */
 void __attribute__ ((unused)) estart (int argc, char*argv[])
 {
     int rval = main(argc,argv);
     exit(rval);
 }

 /* Setup arguments for estart [like main()]. */
 void __attribute__ ((naked)) _start (void)
 {
     asm(" sub     lr, lr, lr\n"   /* Clear the link register. */
         " ldr     r0, [sp]\n"     /* Get argc... */
         " add     r1, sp, #4\n"   /* ... and argv ... */
         " b       estart\n"       /* Let's go! */
         );
 }
```

It is good to clear the `lr` so that stack traces will terminate.  You can avoid the `argc` and `argv` processing if you want.  The `start` shows how to work with this.  The `estart` is just a wrapper to convert the `main()` return code to an `exit()` call.

You need to convert the above assembler to **Thumb** equivalents.  I would suggest using *gcc inline assembler*.  You can convert to pure assembler source if you get inlines to work.  However, doing this in 'C' source is probably more practical, unless you are trying to make a very minimal executable.

Helpful *gcc* arguements are,

```
 -nostartfiles -static -nostdlib -isystem <path to linux user headers>
```

Add `-mthumb` and you should have a harness for either mode.

Comment: Of course your Linux kernel must be configured to support *thumb* binaries.  The code for this is extremely minimal, but it is a `.config` option.

Comment: The command `readelf -h $1 | grep Entry.*[13579bdf]$` should return some text if the elf is a setup to run in *thumb* mode.

Comment: (+1) Nice info, however I wonder if you managed to direct gcc (driver) or linker to actually create `_start` in thumb mode?

Comment: I have generated thumb binaries with *klibc* for an *initramfs*; these binaries link with klibc, but compile with `-nostartfiles` and have a thumb `_start`.  The code above is for an *eglibc* system, but it doesn't use any libraries and is ARM code.  I didn't put the two concepts together.

Comment: @auselen Here is the [klibc startup](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/klibc/arch/arm/crt0.S).  Very similar to the above.  The [libc_init.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/klibc/libc_init.c) is equivalent to `estart()`; but more full featured.

Comment: Ok then, this was nice to know, thanks. I think my sole mistake was to omit `.thumb_func` and try to force `as`, `ld` to create an odd address for `_start`.

Comment: Thanks for the info again and please see my updated answer. Funny thing I've noticed, if you strip the binary then it will create SIGILL. I don't know if that should be considered as a bug or loophole.

Answer (score 0):

here answer.

Thanks for all.

http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/egcs/src/egcs/gcc/config/arm/README-interworking

> - Calls via function pointers should use the `BX` instruction if the call is made in ARM mode:
>
>   ```
>       .code 32
>       mov lr, pc
>       bx  rX
>   ```
>
>   This code sequence will not work in Thumb mode however, since the mov instruction will not set the bottom bit of the `lr` register.  Instead a branch-and-link to the `_call_via_rX` functions should be used instead:
>
>   ```
>       .code 16
>       bl  _call_via_rX
>   ```
>
>   where `rX` is replaced by the name of the register containing the function address.

Comment: This works if you want an infinite loop.  I thought you wanted the program to run and exit; which is where my answer comes from.  Actually, that paper doesn't make any sense.  You have an ARM arm926ejs and it support good inter-networking.  That paper is for CPUs before **ARM ARMv5** without `blx`.  An infinite thumb loop is just `loop: blx loop` or just `loop: b loop`.