# How to cross-compile with GNU autotools for armv5tel?

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, arm, cross-compiling, autotools

I have an ARM machine that runs Linux (BusyBox).

```
# uname -a
# Linux XXXXXXXX 2.6.28 #1 PREEMPT Fri Sep 26 22:47:38 UTC 2014 armv5tel GNU/Linux
```

I've cross-compiled a simple program on my Ubuntu 32-bit desktop:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi LDFLAGS="-static"
make
```

But when I try to run it on the ARM machine, it gives me Segmentation Fault error.

Program is super simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");

    return 0;
}
```

Here are a few things I've already tried/checked:

- I've checked md5 hashes on both machines to eliminate the possibility that something went wrong at the time of copying an executable over the network
- Stripped the executable with `arm-linux-gnueabi-strip`. I was comparing my executable with another executable that was already in the target machine with `file`:

`# file my_program`

`# my_program: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x4b1f2773e54b141d5157b86f0f10438a372625c9, stripped`

`# file their_program`

`# their_program: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **busybox** and arm-linux-**gnueabi**.  Is it possible that one is uClibc and another is eglibc.  Now, you also have softfp type ABI issues.  **armv5tel** will generally not have `fp` registers, so I would specify,  `-mfloat-abi=soft` and select 'softfp' libraries.  It maybe the Ubuntu tool chain you have doesn't support this. In [this question on thumb entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369440/can-start-be-the-thumb-function/), you can find some code that can be compiled with `-nostartfiles -static -nostdlib`, any tool chain can produce Linux binaries that run with these techniques.

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks for uClibc idea, that made me to research on it and finally figuring out the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently my cross-compile toolchain was not the right one.
I ended up using [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/). Btw it's very simple to use and a great tool, all you have to do is to choose the right toolchain for your device.

I have built an `arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi` toolchain with crosstool-ng, which solved my problem.