# Getting a custom ramdisk to boot on Android

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, ramdisk

I am working on a "GNU/Linux on Android" type of project that is based on Mikael Q. Kuisma's work [here](http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian) .

I built a tool that downloads a toolchain, compiles the kernel, archives the custom ramdisk, and finally bundles them into a boot image.

Expected result:

- Kernel boots.
- Ramdisk gets loaded and `/init` is executed using `/sbin/busybox`.

Actual result:

- Kernel does boot.
- The kernel never seems to reach `/init`, and hangs without panicking.

I've tried adding calls to `/sbin/busybox poweroff` in the `/init` script to see if it was actually reaching execution, nothing changed.

I identified a few points that seemed problematic, one being this:

```
[    3.880314] Warning: unable to open an initial console.
[    3.880429] Waiting for root device ... # Might be the problem.
[    4.882304] lct will vote for sdp current
[    4.882437] pmi632_charger: smblib_update_usb_type: lct v02 battery charge APSD=SDP PD=0
[    4.889933] msm-dwc3 7000000.ssusb: DWC3 exited from low power mode
[    5.520181] of_batterydata_get_best_profile: light_4000mAh found
[    8.760236] cfg_timer_func enter
[    8.760267] cfg_work_routine enter
# Nothing appears after this point...
```

I have included the source code for my build tool with the kernel log buffer in [this](https://github.com/EralpCelebi/stromaos) git repository. You can find the defconfig I used for the kernel build [here](https://github.com/EralpCelebi/kernel-xiaomi-onclite/blob/stroma-os/arch/arm64/configs/onclite-stroma_defconfig).

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you populated `/dev/` with some `mknod` commands like */dev/console*, so that busybox could set *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr*.  This is why you can not see anything.

Comment: In the answer [Can thumb be a _start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369440/can-start-be-the-thumb-function/20379933?r=SearchResults&s=2|21.6486#20379933), you can modify/duplicate `exit()` to implement `write()` and print something.  This is a program that is minimal.  If you call `exit()`, you can see the message *init exited!*.  But busybox should work if the devices are setup properly.  Also see [How to populate dev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52713/how-to-populate-dev-directory-when-building-my-own-initrd), where devtmpfs is given as an answer.

Comment: I'll try populating `/dev` and try my luck again. Thanks for the suggestion :)