# Why shows readelf on an ARM binary an odd entry point address?

Tags: arm, elf

I compiled a C++ HelloWorld on an Odroid-XU3 with gcc/g++ version 4.8.2 and clang version 3.5. I also wrote a C HelloWorld for comparison.

`g++ -static -o HelloWorld hello.cc`

`readelf -h HelloWorld` shows the following entry point addresses:

`HelloWorld: 0x8be5
 HelloClang: 0x8c45
 HelloC:     0x88b5`

These are odd addresses. Thumb has odd addresses, so has this something to do with Thumb?

Additionally, `objdump -lSd HelloWorld` shows the `_start` Symbol at `0x8be4`, which looks like the "right" address.

Why show these two tools different addresses?

Comment: Related: [Script/tool for arm-elf to determine thumb/arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913964/script-tool-predicate-for-arm-elf-compiled-for-thumb-or-arm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes addresses are odd because they are Thumb functions, which is a simple question, however why two tools report differently to me is a good question.

`readelf` on purpose doesn't use BFD (unlike objdump) and mostly used to verify other tools against.

[Here](https://github.com/mirror/cygwin/blob/master/binutils/readelf.c#L24):

> The difference between readelf and objdump:   Both programs are
> capable of displaying the contents of ELF format files,   so why does
> the binutils project have two file dumpers ?
>
> The reason is that
> objdump sees an ELF file through a BFD filter of the   world; if BFD
> has a bug where, say, it disagrees about a machine constant   in
> e_flags, then the odds are good that it will remain internally
> consistent.  The linker sees it the BFD way, objdump sees it the BFD
> way,   GAS sees it the BFD way.  There was need for a tool to go find
> out what   the file actually says.
>
> This is why the readelf program
> does not link against the BFD library - it   exists as an independent
> program to help verify the correct working of BFD.
>
> There is also the
> case that readelf can provide more information about an   ELF file
> than is provided by objdump.  In particular it can display DWARF
> debugging information which (at the moment) objdump cannot.